# String#contains using Pattern

Tags: java, regex, string

If I would want to make a 100% clone of `String#contains(CharSequence s): boolean` in Java regex using `Pattern`. Would the following calls be identical?

```
input.contains(s);
```

and

```
Pattern.compile(".*" + Pattern.quote(s) + ".*").matcher(input).matches();
```

---

Similarly, would the following code have the same functionality?

```
Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(s)).matcher(input).find();
```

---

I presume that the regex search is less performant, but only by a constant factor. Is this correct? Is there any way to optimize the regular expressions to mimic `contains`?

---

The reason that I'm asking is that I have a piece of code that is written around `Pattern` and it seems wasteful to create a separate piece of code that uses `contains`. On the other hand, I don't want different test results - even minor ones - for each code. Are there any Unicode related differences, for instance?

Comment: If you need to use a matcher for this, use `Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(s)).matcher(input).find();`. The `.*` will not match line breaks by default (you need `(?s)` at the start or `Pattern.DOTALL`) and will cause too much backtracking.

Comment: That's dang close to an answer Wiktor... care to write one? Interesting difference between `find` and `matches` there.

Comment: Personally, I'd find it wasteful to use `Pattern` to do what `contains` does, from a runtime perspective. `Pattern`s need to be compiled, a `Matcher` created, then the match checked - all this just to do a simple substring as in `String#contains`.

Comment: FYI, `String#contains` is a lot faster than regex contains. I hope you have a requirement to use regex contains.

Comment: @ArunGowda I don't have a requirement, but I do have a reason w.r.t. code complexity.

Comment: So next in line would be to use regex to get a substring or use regex to replace `startsWith`, `endsWith` etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to write a `.contains` like method based on [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), you should choose the [`Matcher#find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) version:

```
Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(s)).matcher(input).find()
```

If you want to use `.matches()`, you should bear in mind that:

- `.*` will not match line breaks by default and you need `(?s)` inline modifier at the start of the pattern or use [`Pattern.DOTALL` option](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL)
- The  `.*` at the pattern start will cause too much backtracking and you may get a stack overflow  exception, or the code execution might just freeze.

Comment: Nice. Do you have any idea if the `find` will be faster than the `Pattern.DOTALL`? That would be counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes You can't compare `Matcher#find()` and `Pattern.DOTALL`. The former allows finding partial matches and the latter just enables `.` to match line break chars.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to see if a String matches a Pattern:

```
return Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(s)).asPredicate().test(input);
```

or

```
return Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(s)).matcher.find(input);
```

There is no need for matching on .*. this will match anything surrounding the actual result and just be overhead.

Comment: Never mind, looked at the source code of `asPredicate`: `return s -> matcher(s).find()`. Uh, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

This just to share how I decided to solve this little conundrum. I've redesigned by library to not take a `Pattern` but to take a predicate, like this:

```
public static Set<String> findAll() {
    return find(input -> true);
}

public static Set<String> findSubstring(String s) {
    return find(input -> input.contains(s));
}

public static Set<String> findPattern(Pattern p) {
    return find(p.asPredicate());
}

public static Set<String> findCaseInsensitiveSubstring(String s) {
    return find(Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(s), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).asPredicate());
}

private static Set<String> find(Predicate<String> matcher) {
    var testInput = Set.of("some", "text", "to", "test");
    return testInput.stream().filter(matcher).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(findAll());
    System.out.println(findSubstring("t"));
    System.out.println(findPattern(Pattern.compile("^[^s]")));
    System.out.println(findCaseInsensitiveSubstring("T"));
}
```

where I've used all the comments and answers given up to now.

Note that there is also `Pattern#asMatchPredicate()` in case matching is required instead, e.g. for a function `matchPattern`.

Of course above is just a demonstration, not the actual functions in my solution.